# Drawing a line on an image

Tags: processing

I have stuck up in a problem. This question is with respect to processing. I have to draw a scratch on an image using this function

```html
line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
```

How do I achieve this? I mean, wherever I draw a scratch, pixel corresponding to that image has to be updated.

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of effect do you want to achieve so here is basic usage of drawing line according to mouse position.

```java
PImage  img;    //global variable for storing image

void setup(){
  img = loadImage("image.jpg");    //loading image  
  size(img.width, img.height);    //setting size of sketch
}

void draw(){    
  image(img, 0, 0);        //each time redraw background with Image

  line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);  //draw line acc to mouse
}
```

If you want to draw big line just move `image()` function into `setup()`. 
If you want more complicated lines you will have to use [mouse events](https://www.processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html).